# how to install tomcat server and mysql db within same docker container using dockerfile?

Tags: linux, mysql, docker

I know that its better to use seperate containers for mysql and tomcat and link them before deploying them , but since i want to deploy this using kubectl(kubernetes) its easier if its done on a single same container and can be readily deployed using the deployment and service yaml files of kubernetes.

what changes do I have to make to my docker file and yaml files to make tomcat interact with the sql database??

Dockerfile

```
FROM tomcat

COPY data-core-test.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
```

deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: tomcat-pod
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: tomcat-pod
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: tomcat-pod
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: tomcat
        image: tomcat:warfile
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: tomcat-pod
  labels:
    run: tomcat-pod
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    run: tomcat-pod
```

Answer (score 0):

You will find that managing multiple processes inside one container can be troublesome in the long run. Besides... Kubernetes allows you to [run multiple containers in one Pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-overview/).

Application processes will be mostly isolated, but they do share the same network interface -- meaning that, inside the Pod, all containers can be accessed as `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.

Containers inside the Pod are treated as a single unit. They will always be scheduled on the same host and restarted simultaneously, following the Pod's life cycle.

Comment: hi today i tried running both tomcat and mysql containers on a single pod!!!!

Comment: the thing is I am able to access the tomcat home page using  my server IP address: node port but can't access my app using IP address: node port/data-core-test